# How to invoke an element of a "combo box" by default in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to call an element of a "combo box" with its respective associated function by default when starting my program in Tkinter, I could do it with an "OptionMenu" with the following code

```
WidgetName=ttk.OptionMenu(root,Variable,'item 1','item 2', command=function)
WidgetName.pack()
WidgetName["menu"].invoke(index=1)
```

But it doesn't work with the "combobox"

```
WidgetName = ttk.Combobox(root)
WidgetName.pack()
WidgetName['values']=['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4']
WidgetName.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", function)
WidgetName['menu'].invoke(index=0)

_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"
```

I know that you can set a value with a variable using the "set" command, but what I want is not only to change the name, but also to call the corresponding function, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Do you simply mean you want to execute `function` with a parameter which is the item selected on `Combobox`?

Comment: Yes, it is what I want to do